# ¿Como superponer paneles en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Visual Studio C#, quiero poner un panel encima de otro y con unos botones mostrar el panel que yo quiero, pero al momento de hacer esto, solo me muestra el contenido de un panel pero el del otro no, este es el código que puse:

```
private void ElbtnRH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//boton1
    {
        pRH.Visible = true;
        pRH.BringToFront();
        pAlmacen.Visible = false;
        pAlmacen.SendToBack();
    }

    private void ElbtnAlmacen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//boton2
    {
        pAlmacen.Visible = true;
        pAlmacen.Visible = true;
        pAlmacen.BringToFront();
        pRH.Visible = false;
        pRH.SendToBack();
    }
```

pero sigo sin poder resolverlo.

Comment: si estas ocultando el panel ni siquiera necesitarias ponerlo en primer plano o en segundo, solo deberias funcionar con el Visible, pero la verdad no veo porque solo te muestre uno solamente. Si los separas un poco para ver que esten ambos puede ver algun otro efecto?

Comment: estas seguro que pRH y pAlmacen son las instancias de lo paneles? digo no haces ningun `new` ni nada de eso, no? porque entonces no serian las instancias que visualizas en el form, debes usar el nombre que le diste a los controles

Comment: si los paneles los pongo separandos, es decir, uno arriba y otro abajo si hace la función, si le doy clic a un boton me muestra un panel y el otro lo oculta, pero cuando los pongo en la misma posición, solo me muestra el pRH y el pAlmacen no me muestra nada

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude solucionar, buscando un poco más encontré que en esos casos se usa el Hide() y el Show, entonces el código quedaría así;

```
private void ElbtnRH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pRH.Show();
        pAlmacen.Hide();
    }

    private void ElbtnAlmacen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pAlmacen.Show();
        pRH.Hide();
    }
```

y en vez de ocultarlos con la propiedad Visible del control, los oculto con Hide()